# Android Material shadow looks weird with custom OutlineProvider

Tags: android, material-design, android-tablayout

I trying to add a shadow to a `View`. Specifically a bottom aligned `TabLayout` which, by default, does not have a shadow.

I created a custom `OutlineProvider` and applied it to the `TabLayout` like so

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    TabLayout tabs = (TabLayout)findViewById(R.id.tabs);
    tabs.setOutlineProvider(new ViewOutlineProviderTabs());
}

public class ViewOutlineProviderTabs extends ViewOutlineProvider {
    @Override
    public void getOutline(View view, Outline outline) {
        //create a rectangular outline
        outline.setRect(0,-25,view.getWidth(),view.getHeight());
    }
}
```

The shadow look close to correct but has some extra, unexplained lines

How it looks:

[image: Weird Shadow example]

How it should look:

[image]

The top image is not a smooth gradient, it looks like it has two lines.

Is there a way to fix this bizarre rendering? Or another approach to add a shadow to a bottom aligned `TabLayout`?

Answer (score 0):

This is the best I could come up with. I removed the custom `OutlineProvider`. Instead I created a drawable like this:

```
<!--upshadow.xml-->
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item>
        <layer-list>
            <item >
                <shape>
                    <gradient android:angle="90"
                        android:endColor="#00000000" android:startColor="#45000000"
                        android:centerY="25%"
                        android:centerColor="#25000000"/>
                </shape>
            </item>
        </layer-list>
    </item>

</selector>
```

Then I created a `View` above the `TabLayout` with the shadow as the background

```
    <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/tabs"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        />
    <View
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="8dp"
        android:layout_above="@id/tabs"
        android:background="@drawable/upshadow"
    />
```

It looks basically stock and has causes no obvious problems. Things like `ScrollView`s will even render under it like they do in normal shadows.